# My subsequent div backgrounds don't show up if I put a text animation effect in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

CSS3 for the animation where the idea is to fade in certain words on a continuous loop basis.

```
<style>
.rw-words{
display: inline;
text-indent: 10px;
}
.rw-words-1 h3{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
overflow: hidden;
color: #6b969d;
-webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
-moz-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
-o-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
-ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 h3:nth-child(2) { 
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
-moz-animation-delay: 3s; 
-o-animation-delay: 3s; 
-ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
animation-delay: 3s; 
color: #6b889d;
}
.rw-words-1 h3:nth-child(3) { 
-webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
-moz-animation-delay: 6s; 
-o-animation-delay: 6s; 
-ms-animation-delay: 6s; 
animation-delay: 6s; 
color: #6b739d; 


@keyframes rotateWord {
0% { opacity: 0; }
2% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-30px); }
5% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0px);}
17% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0px); }
20% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(30px); }
80% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}

</style>
```

Animation ends

```
<div class="slideContainers" id="sC1">
```

1.Text-animation where h3 elements are supposed to fade in

```
<span class="demo4"> We do the
<div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
<h3>zumba</h3>
<h3>rumba</h3>
<h3>happiness</h3>


              </div> 
           here.   </span>
```

2. Text animation ends

```
        </div><!-- sC1 ends -->   
        </div><!-- slide1 ends -->
```

3. Slide2 whose background goes invisible

```
    <div id="slide2" class="slide" data-slide="2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="slideContainers" id="sC2">
            <h1 class="pageTitle">About Us</h1>
            <p id="aboutCopy" class="copy">When there's a lot on your plate, putting real good food, from real good ingredients, on the dinner table can be a hassle.<br>
But imagine if the easy answer to "What's for dinner?" was the better one for you.        </p>

        </div><!-- sC2 ends -->    
    </div><!-- slide2 ends -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried without `0s` at end ? i.e.g, `animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite;` ? `animation-delay` `property` at post may not be positioned at correct order according to syntax guidelines

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Syntax

```
Syntax
Formal syntax: <single-animation-name> || <time> || <timing-function> || <time> || <single-animation-iteration-count> || <single-animation-direction> || <single-animation-fill-mode>

The order is important within each animation definition: the first value that can be parsed as a <time> is assigned to the animation-duration, and the second one is assigned to animation-delay.
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. Donno how i missed it. I have corrected it but however it has no effect on my error. Still no backgrounds displayed.

Comment: @NitishParab Does not appear where a `background` property is set within the `css` ? Neither general `css` properties, not `@keyframes` ? If possible, can create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Here is my [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nitish_8/84Fwf/13/) to the jsfiddle  For some reason the links aren't working but you can scroll and see the issue. Because of the test animation in 'slide1', the backgrounds of slide2 & slide5 don't show up. I tried to single out the problem and so far i think the 'data-stellar-background-ratio' property is clashing with the css3 'keyframes'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @NitishParab `html`, `css` from jsfiddle a) `css` have **same issue as from original post**, i.e.g., around _line 132_:`-webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;` at **_0s_** b) `html` element nesting issue, i.e.g., at `#slide1`, `div.rw-words` child of `span.demo4`; c) extra `</div>` at `#slide1` close; d) extra `</div>` at `#slide4` cloase. Address `html` and `css` syntax issues ? `animation` syntax issue at original question not adjusted ? Perhaps adjust `html`, `css` syntax, accept or not post to original question, post new question ? Happy to help if able Thanks